# UICollectionView with two headers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Having two headers in UICollectionView?

I've got a UICollectionView which uses the flow layout, which also has a header and footer:

```
---------   
| head  |
---------
| A | B |
---------
| C | D |
---------
| foot  |
---------
```

Occasionally, I'd like to have two headers, like so:

```
---------   
| head1 |
---------   
| head2 |
---------
| A | B |
---------
| C | D |
---------
| foot  |
---------
```

I'm stuck on how to achieve this. The flow layout only appears to allow one head and one foot. How can I add a second header?

---

edit: I have also implemented sticky headers - http://blog.radi.ws/post/32905838158/sticky-headers-for-uicollectionview-using - but I only want the first header to be sticky. This is why I can't just include everything in one header.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You just need to use a simple trick.Show header and footer both for all sections.

In which section you do not want to show footer just pass its size zero as :--

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section==0)
    {
        return CGSizeZero;
    }

    return CGSizeMake(320, 50);
}
```

Here I have used two sections like

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 2;
}
```

And passed no of rows in only one sections that is the last one as

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section==1) {
        return 20;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my output ---

[image]

**Red View is header and Green One is footer.**

[Here u can get the entire Implementation File](https://gist.github.com/ipreencekmr/6220473)

Comment: This seems like a good direction to go. With this method could I use different layouts for the two headers? And allow me to let one header be 'sticky' and the other one to scroll normally.

Comment: yeah why not , just apply section condition on viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind and u can get header of different layouts for each section.

Comment: How can i set CustomFlowLayout only section 2?

Answer (score 5):

This content may help you to achieve what you want

create the class `CollectionHeaderView` and make it to derive from `UICollectionReusableView` and make container, And then after make 2 uiview and put it to this container

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        CollectionHeaderView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        headerView.firstContainer.titleLabel.text = @"MY Header View 1";//Here you can set title 

        headerView.secondContainer.titleLabel.text = @"MY Header View 2";//Here you can set title  
        UIImage *headerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header_banner.png"];
        headerView.firstContainer.backgroundImage.image = headerImage;
       headerView.secondContainer.backgroundImage.image = headerImage;

        reusableview = headerView;
    }

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {
        UICollectionReusableView *footerview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"FooterView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        reusableview = footerview;
    }

    return reusableview;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is advised to post the necessary information in the answer body itself. Link only answers are discouraged.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Ok I did this.. Thanks :)

Comment: For further reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 4):

You should put both the header (1 and 2) in an other view and place that view as head 1. Thus create just on header in the collection view.

Comment: Still this should work, just don't think about them as being two header.

Comment: I can't think how this would work since the headers have different behaviours.

Answer (score 2):

How are you adding one header? I suppose by specifying section headers? The recipe to have two headers would be to have two header subviews inside one header main view.

Comment: You can try different autoresize masks with both header subviews.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is use a UITableView with two sections and put the UICollectionView in the cell of the second section.

Answer (score 2):

Define your UICollectionViewCell which will be your Header view of kind UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader - In my case I have two headers - OfferHeaderCell and APRHeaderCell defined as below:

```
verticalCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "OfferHeaderCell", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "OfferHeaderCell")
verticalCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "APRHeaderCell", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "APRHeaderCell")
```

Go ahead and return a header for each section and then set the size of the section header to have a size of zero in this UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    if(section==0) {
        return CGSize.zero
    } else if (section==1) {
        return CGSize(width:collectionView.frame.size.width, height:133)
    } else {
        return CGSize(width:collectionView.frame.size.width, height:100)
    }

}
```

Important to define the viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind for two different sections as below:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    var reusableview = UICollectionReusableView()
    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        let section = indexPath.section
        switch (section) {
        case 1:
            let  firstheader: OfferHeaderCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "OfferHeaderCell", for: indexPath) as! OfferHeaderCell
            reusableview = firstheader
        case 2:
            let  secondHeader: APRHeaderCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "APRHeaderCell", for: indexPath) as! APRHeaderCell
            reusableview = secondHeader
        default:
            return reusableview

        }
    }
    return reusableview
}
```

And lastly the Datasource,

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (section==2) {
        return 2
    }
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = verticalCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ReviseOfferCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return cell
}
```

Note: Don't forgot to add UICollectionFlowLayout as below:

// MARK: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

```
extension MakeAnOfferController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

            if indexPath.item == 0 {
                return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 626.0)
            }
            return CGSize()
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

            if(section==0) {
                return CGSize.zero
            } else if (section==1) {
                return CGSize(width:collectionView.frame.size.width, height:133)
            } else {
                return CGSize(width:collectionView.frame.size.width, height:100)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got this working by creating two views in a reusable header, implement sticky header only if the section is the second section. Also, I adjust the numberOfSection to 2. Got the headers switching by hiding and showing the views in viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind.